# How exclude testng groups via maven?

Tags: maven, testng

How can I exclude a specific testng test groups via maven?

```
mvn test -Dexcludegroups
```

does not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excluding TestNG Groups From Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150302/excluding-testng-groups-from-maven)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to mention the tag in `pom.xml` that you use to exclude groups:

For example, pom snippet:

```
<exclude.tag>unstable</exclude.tag>
<excludes>
    <tag>${exclude.tag}</tag>                       
</excludes>
```

You may use below :

```
mvn test -Dexclude.tag=excludegroups
```

Also in `TestNg`, the `testng.xml` provides this ability by mentioning the `exclude-group` in exclude tag as below:

```
<suite name="Exclude Group Suite" verbose="1">
  <test name="Exclude Group Test">
    <groups>
      <run>
        <include name="include-group" />
        <exclude name="exclude-group" />
      </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
      <class name="ExcludeGroupTest" />
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Reference : [TestNG – Test Groups, Meta Group, Default Group Examples](https://howtodoinjava.com/testng/testng-test-groups-meta-group-default-group-examples/)